# Matching multiple kinds of dates/timestamps using regex

Tags: python, regex, datetime, timestamp

I have a file with two different types of dates/timestamps. First of all, I have date/timestamps formatted like so:

```
DATE    : Fri, 20 Apr 2012 09:15:17 -0700 (PDT)
```

Secondly, I have timestamps formatted like so:

```
12:24 PM
```

I wrote two regex patterns to deal with this:

```
full_pattern = re.compile('\w{3,4}\W\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')
time_pattern = re.compile(' \d:\d\d\s[\w]{2}')
```

These are conversations, so I'm looking for an output that has the date and time the conversation started, and then the timestamps for each item in the conversation. The ultimate application of this is to actuate something using an Arduino microcontroller every time the date and time matches up (i.e: is it April 30th and 1:01pm? Was there a message then? Yes? Okay, actuate).

I have two questions:

1. The first pattern("full_pattern") doesn't return anything, and I can't figure out why. Do I need to address the full lines? (Include the "DATE" bit)?
2. How do I use these together? So the regular expression finds the first date/timestamp and then prints out the timestamps, finds the next date/timestamp and then prints out the timestamps. Like so:

   Fri, 20 Apr 2012 11:01:17
     11:01 AM
     11:03 AM

   Fri, 20 Apr 2012 09:15:17
     9:15 PM
     9:17 PM

Please note: the date/timestamps are in military time and the others are AM/PM

I've tried piping it like so:

```
 re.findall(pattern1 | pattern2, string)
```

But it didn't like that. I also tried running them concurrently in a for loop, like so:

```
 for line in string:
         pattern1 = re.compile('\w{3,4}\W\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')
         pattern2 = re.compile(' \d:\d\d\s[\w]{2}')
         re.findall(pattern1, string)
         re.findall(pattern2, string)
```

But that resulted in an infinite loop of all pattern2 (possibly not infinite, definitely way more than I needed).

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing regular expressions on-line helps troubleshoot your regular expressions that don't work.  I used [this one](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Here's the Python I used to solve your problem:

```
import re

full_pattern = r'\w{3,4}\W\s\d{1,2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
time_pattern = r'\d{1,2}:\d{2}(\s(A|P)M)?'
combo_regex = '(%s)' % ('|'.join([full_pattern, time_pattern]),)

with open(r'C:\Users\spikem\file_with_two_different_types_of_dates.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        p = re.search(combo_regex, line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if p:
            print p.group() # Assumes a max of one match per line
```

And here is some sample output:

```
Fri, 20 Apr 2012 09:15:17
12:24 PM
Tue, 10 Jan 2012 00:00:00
Fri, 20 Jan 2012 00:00:00
Mon, 30 Jan 2012 00:00:00
Thu, 09 Feb 2012 00:00:00
Sun, 19 Feb 2012 00:00:00
Wed, 29 Feb 2012 00:00:00
Sat, 10 Mar 2012 00:00:00
Tue, 20 Mar 2012 00:00:00
Fri, 30 Mar 2012 00:00:00
Mon, 09 Apr 2012 00:00:00
Thu, 19 Apr 2012 00:00:00
Sun, 29 Apr 2012 00:00:00
Wed, 09 May 2012 00:00:00
Sat, 19 May 2012 00:00:00
Tue, 29 May 2012 00:00:00
Fri, 08 Jun 2012 00:00:00
Mon, 18 Jun 2012 00:00:00
Thu, 28 Jun 2012 00:00:00
Sun, 08 Jul 2012 00:00:00
Wed, 18 Jul 2012 00:00:00
Sat, 28 Jul 2012 00:00:00
Tue, 07 Aug 2012 00:00:00
Fri, 17 Aug 2012 00:00:00
Mon, 27 Aug 2012 00:00:00
Thu, 06 Sep 2012 00:00:00
Sun, 16 Sep 2012 00:00:00
Wed, 26 Sep 2012 00:00:00
Sat, 06 Oct 2012 00:00:00
Tue, 16 Oct 2012 00:00:00
Fri, 26 Oct 2012 00:00:00
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just tested this out and getting great results. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

im posting this as an answer since i dont have the rep to post as comment.

http://www.txt2re.com/

Just paste the text you want to do a regex search on and start selecting things to catch and you get code examples in different langs :)

this tool is simply amazing.

Might this work for you?
http://www.txt2re.com/index-python.php3?s=DATE%20%20%20%20:%20Fri,%2020%20Apr%202012%2009:15:17%20-0700%20%28PDT%29%20&28&6&3&2&8&13&29&12

Comment: Oh awesome, I'd heard of these types of tools but have always tried to headbutt my way through my problems...maybe it's time to test them out.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of fixes to your first pattern:

```
\w{3,4},\s\d{1,2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d
```

(1) If you're expecting a comma after the day name, go ahead and be explicit about it.

(2) You're missing the part of the pattern to detect the day of month.

I'm trusting that your pattern corresponds to your input, that is, that day names will be exactly 3 or 4 characters, and that each element is separated by exactly 1 space.

I think you want this for your second pattern:

```
\s\d{1,2}:\d\d\s(AM|PM)
```

I'm not sure whether your input has that leading space.  You may want

```
\d{1,2}:\d\d\s(AM|PM)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your format so this is just an example.
If its the that the line only alters by time format, you could use a single regex to get all the information at once.

```
\b  ([a-z])+,      # (1) # Fri,
\s+ (\d+)          # (2) # 20
\s+ ([a-z]+)       # (3) # Apr
\s+ (\d+)          # (4) # 2012
\s+ (\d+:\d+:\d+)  # (5) # 11:01:17

(?:                 # Time Zone
    \s+ (-\d+)           # (6) # -0700
    \s+ \( ([a-z]) \)    # (7) # (PDT)

  |                # OR,

                     # Local time 1
   \s+ (\d+:\d+)        # (8) # 11:01
   \s+ ([a-z]+)         # (9) # AM
   (?:               # Local time 2 (optional)
      \s+ (\d+:\d+)     # (10) # 11:03
      \s+ ([a-z]+)      # (11) # AM
   )?
)
```